# How to remove pre-installed VirtualBox Guest Additions from Linux Mint 18?

Tags: linux-mint, virtualbox

I am quite new to Linux. So far I used Ubuntu for a few months. Now after I installed Linux Mint 18 on VirtualBox, and tried to install VirtualBox Guest Additions into it, the installer says that it's already installed from another source and I have to remove it to install the new one.

I know I can continue with the current version, but how do I remove it? What packages need to be uninstalled and what conf filed need to be edited?

Answer (score 1):

170 views, no answers. I've tried the various methods suggested on Mint and Ubuntu's forum. All managed to remove (most of) the pre-installed version of guest additions. However, on reboot before or after installing the correct version of the guest additions for the actual version of virtualbox I use, just end up with a black screen (cinnamon) or unresponsive KDE screen with no widgets.

The only solution I've found is to download a version of it from OS Boxes, which is built without guest additions pre-installed:

https://www.osboxes.org/linux-mint/

If you trust them! Searching their name didn't flag up any issues, though. The downside is, they're pre-built disk images, not installation ISOs.

Answer (score 1):

Just run:

```
sudo apt purge virtualbox*
```

This will remove all the pre-installed packages that are giving you trouble. Then insert the guest additions image and re-run the autoinstaller, and you should be good to go.